# Merge two list of tuples based on overlapp python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

Given two lists x, y such that they both have been initialized as shown below:

```
x = [(0, 3), (5, 8), (16, 19), (21, 24), (28, 30), (40, 42), (46, 47), (50, 54), (58, 63), (69, 71)]
y = [(9, 10), (26, 27), (29, 31), (35, 36), (41, 43), (48, 49), (66, 67), (70, 72), (77, 78), (85, 86)]
```

I want to form a new list of tuples where each tuple has contiguous tuples from x and an overlapping tuple from y.

For the example above, the output would be:

```
[((5, 8) (9, 10) (16, 19)), ((21, 24) (26, 27) (28, 30)), ((28, 30) (29, 31) (40, 42)), ((28, 30) (35, 36) (40, 42)), ((40, 42) (41, 43) (46, 47)), ((46, 47) (48, 49) (50, 54)),((58, 63) (66, 67) (69, 71))]
```

My code:

```
lst = []
for i in range(len(x)):
  if i+1 < len(x):
    context = x[i],x[i+1]
    for j in y:
      if j[0] >= context[0][0] and j[0] <= context[1][0]:
        lst.append((context[0],j,context[1]))
```

I need better and efficient ways to write this code.

Comment: Can you explain more? Where is tuple `(0, 3)`? Also, is `(16, 19)` overlaping `(5, 8)` and `(9, 10)` ?

Comment: Tuple (0,3) is absent in the output because there is no element in y that can cause an overlap between (0,3) and (5,8). The 9 in (9,10) in y is greater than 8.

Comment: Because 41 is greater than 40 and less than 47

Comment: @JesujobaALABI If my answer solves your problem, please consider marking it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two variables to keep track of indices in x and y list. Using the conditions specified in the problem, these indices can be incremented whenever the given condition has been satisfied.
At every iteration, the algorithm checks if `x[i][0] < y[j][0]` and `x[i+1][1] > y[j][1]` ( The upper and lower bound provided by the contigous tuples in `x`. If this condition is true, we increment `j` (y-index) so that we can check if the next element lies in the given range. Else, we increment `i` (x-index) and repeat the process.

```
x = [(0, 3), (5, 8), (16, 19), (21, 24), (28, 30), (40, 42), (46, 47), (50, 54), (58, 63), (69, 71)]
y = [(9, 10), (26, 27), (29, 31), (35, 36), (41, 43), (48, 49), (66, 67), (70, 72), (77, 78), (85, 86)]

i = 0
j = 0
result = list()

while i < len(x) - 1 and j < len(y):
    if y[j][0] > x[i][0] and y[j][1] < x[i + 1][1]:
        result.append((x[i], y[j], x[i + 1]))
        j += 1
    else:
        i += 1
print(result)
```

Output -

```
[((5, 8), (9, 10), (16, 19)),
 ((21, 24), (26, 27), (28, 30)),
 ((28, 30), (29, 31), (40, 42)),
 ((28, 30), (35, 36), (40, 42)),
 ((40, 42), (41, 43), (46, 47)),
 ((46, 47), (48, 49), (50, 54)),
 ((58, 63), (66, 67), (69, 71))]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Python Sorting](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

```
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter
output = sorted((x + y), key=itemgetter(0))
```

Comment: Could you please post the output of this code for the sample input and indicate how it matches with the given sample output?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, it seems that I misunderstood the question.
Thank you for pointing out :)